# There is no quasiregular diffeomorphism from punctured ball into ring (on the plane)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

The idea is to use l2 cohomology as a quasiregular map invariant.
It is easy to see that there are closed 1-forms on the ring which are not exact, but it occures that *every* closed l2-form
$f_1(x,y)dx + f_2(x,y)dy$
is exact. Here $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $C^{\infty}(B_1\backslash\{0\})\cap L^2(B_1\backslash\{0\})$ functions. The ball $B_1$ is open.
I have got some problems with the proof.
I want to prove that $\int_{x^y+y^2=r^2}f_1dx+f_2dy=0$ for any $0<r\leq 1$.
Then, as the form is exact, this integral doesn`t depend on radius $r$. So by using the polar coordinates and the previous remark we can write:
$r\int_0^{2\pi}f_2(r,\varphi)\cos(\varphi)-f_1(r,\varphi)\sin(\varphi)d\varphi=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_0^\varepsilon r\int_0^{2\pi}f_2(r,\varphi)\cos(\varphi)-f_1(r,\varphi)\sin(\varphi)d\varphi dr$
This holds for any $\varepsilon>0$. I am trying to get some upper inequalities in order to prove that this is zero but the standart ones seems not to be useful here.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is how to get necessary inequalities which show that this integral is equal to zero.